# Can JSON Schema core keywords be redefined?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, extensibility

I would like to redefine the "title" keyword in JSON Schema to have a different structure: an object with two properties, one for "singular" and one for "plural".

Is this possible? Or do I need a new keyword?

([Section 5.6 of the Core spec](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor20) reads as follows: "Implementations MAY choose to define additional keywords to JSON Schema.")

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is room for additional properties, but the defined properties cannot be redefined.

That would also break a lot of the tools using the schema, if you use any generic ones.